# video_player does not play network Video on IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter

video_player does not play network Video on IOS Simulator.
NSAppTransportSecurity was added to info.plist.

https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

I did add here .

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      widget.videoLink,
      videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(),
    )..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });

    _controller.play();
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

```
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a SSL certificate in which the video is uploaded